# Input value saved in child component's state disappears when the search filter is applied on the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a child component called, `Book`, and a parent component called, `Books`.

Within the child component, I provide users with an `input` to add a genre tag. These tags are not persisted anywhere and is solely saved in `genreTags`.

In the parent component, I have a search filter set up to filter the book by its title, but whenever my search terms filter out certain books and I backspace, my child component rerenders and my tags are subsequently removed.

**Is there anyway to prevent this type of rerendering or is there a way to persist the tags' data (aside from persisting into the backend, which I don't have access to)?** I've tried moving the genreTags' state into the parent component, but this causes all the books to have the same genre tags.

**Parent Component:**

```
export default function Books() {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([])
  const [searchTitle, setSearchTitle] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://www.someapi/books`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(setBooks)
  }, [])

  const filterBooks = books.filter(book => {
    return book.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTitle.toLowerCase())
  })

  const book = filterBooks.map(book => {
    return (
        <Book 
            key={book.id} 
            book={book}
        />
    )
  })

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <Search
        searchTitle={searchTitle}
        onSearchTitle={setSearchTitle}
      />
      {book}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
export default function Book({ book }) 
    const [genreTags, setGenreTags] = useState([])

    function handleAddGenre(e) {
        const val = {
            id: book.id,
            label: e.target.value,
        }

        if (e.key === 'Enter' && val) {
            if (genreTags.find(genre => genre.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase())) {
              return
            }
            setGenreTags([...genreTags, val])
            e.target.value = ""
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="book-div">
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>Written By: {author}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="tag-div">
            <ul> 
                { genreTags && genreTags.map(tag => {
                    return <li key={uuid()}> {tag.label} </li>  
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Add a genre"
            onKeyDown={handleAddGenre} 
        />
    );
}
```

**Search Component:**

```
    return (
        <div className="search">
            <input 
                placeholder="Search by title"
                value={searchTitle}
                onChange={e => onSearchTitle(e.target.value)} 
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a prop in the `Book` to check render or not. Like this:

```
// remove filterBooks

const book = books.map((book) => {
  const isShow = book.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTitle.toLowerCase());
  return <Book key={book.id} book={book} isShow={isShow} />;
});
```

And in the `Book`:

```
export default function Book({ book, isShow }) {
  ...
  if (!isShow) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="book-div">
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>Written By: {author}</p>
    </div>
    ...
  );
}
```